# Hide menu with jQuery, then make reappear with CSS3 Media Queries

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

Hopefully this should be a simple one but just can't quite figure it out. I'm making a little responsive menu which displays as an inline-block along the top of the page when window is greater than 800px wide. When below this, the nav disappears and is replaced with a toggle button which, when clicked, pops up the nav below and to the left.

This all works fine, however one slight bug in the code is that if you resize the window to below 800px, toggle the menu on and then off again, then resize the window back to above 800px, the menu no longer shows along the top as the jQuery has hidden it.

Is it possible to rewrite my media query more effectively so that any time the window is resized above 800px it displays the menu without fail? I originally wrote a little jQuery which constantly checks for $(window).width() to be above 800, but that seems like a really clumsy solution.

Thanks!
Fraser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Refined Responsive Menu</title>

        <style>

            /* General Styles */

            body{
                font-family: Helvetica, Sans;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .container{
                max-width: 1000px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            .content{
                min-height: 2000px;
                padding-top: 80px;
            }

            .content p{
                padding-left: 30px;
                padding-right: 30px;
            }


            /* Navigation Bar */

            nav{
                background: #222;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;

                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
            }

            nav ul{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                max-width: 1000px;
            }

            nav ul li{
                display: inline-block;
            }

            nav ul li a{
                color: #FFF;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 20px 30px;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            nav ul li a:hover{
                background: #444;
            }

            div.toggle-menu-btn{
                display: none;

                background: #222;
                color: #FFF;
                padding: 20px 30px;

                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
            }

            div.toggle-menu-btn:hover{
                background: #444;
                cursor:pointer;
            }


            /* Media Queries */

            @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

                div.toggle-menu-btn{
                    display: inline-block;
                }

                nav{
                    display: none;

                    margin-top: 60px;
                    width: 50%;
                    min-width: 200px;
                }

                nav ul li{
                    display: block;
                }

                nav ul li a{
                    display: block;
                }



            }

        </style>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.toggle-menu-btn').click(function(){
                    $('nav').toggle();
                });

            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="toggle-menu-btn">Toggle</div>

        <nav>

            <div class="container">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>

        <div class="container content">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce purus quam, scelerisque id felis eget, sollicitudin vulputate est. Suspendisse ultrices tortor non feugiat rutrum. Vestibulum et quam nec est sollicitudin luctus. Nam dapibus est orci, et ultrices dolor dapibus suscipit. Nullam at ligula justo. Donec justo ligula, aliquet nec sapien nec, venenatis porttitor nibh. Proin a neque in metus accumsan auctor. Cras imperdiet risus ut mauris gravida, id ultrices velit condimentum. Proin non justo at lectus volutpat imperdiet.</p>

        <p>Sed tempus sodales luctus. Suspendisse ullamcorper feugiat urna, eu convallis lacus rutrum eget. Aenean vitae facilisis elit, nec sagittis lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris et molestie eros. Donec eget imperdiet nisi. Donec pretium justo in sollicitudin hendrerit. Duis ac turpis libero. Sed justo augue, sodales porttitor diam id, pretium venenatis lectus. Donec a sem ut libero ornare tincidunt ut vitae felis.</p>

        <p>In ultrices sodales mattis. Morbi porta sapien tellus, tempor aliquet risus egestas adipiscing. Integer accumsan lobortis consectetur. Quisque hendrerit elit tortor, id cursus arcu interdum in. Cras consequat, odio eget suscipit auctor, tortor odio tristique velit, sed cursus erat mi vitae mi. Maecenas hendrerit ante ut elit elementum bibendum. Fusce cursus, mi sit amet semper hendrerit, justo nunc pharetra turpis, sed condimentum orci elit sed arcu. Maecenas eu tempor turpis. Aenean luctus eu enim in dictum. Duis adipiscing in tortor sed fermentum. Ut cursus sed erat eu elementum. Nulla eget nibh a sem tempus dictum. Sed tempus orci ac accumsan euismod. Sed consequat nibh quis ipsum dictum adipiscing. Integer non risus tortor. Donec molestie tincidunt justo sed rhoncus.</p>

        <p>In elementum eget orci nec luctus. Duis id tellus tellus. Mauris sodales elit et mi cursus feugiat sit amet vitae felis. Sed et sem vitae turpis auctor vestibulum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus a sagittis metus. Pellentesque blandit libero tincidunt, fringilla felis non, porta dolor. Mauris dictum enim at laoreet eleifend. Vivamus dictum eleifend volutpat. Etiam ultricies ultricies elit ac pellentesque. Suspendisse mollis lorem viverra varius volutpat. Mauris pretium lacus quis facilisis dictum. Praesent vel nisl quis enim auctor dignissim.</p>

        <p>Maecenas et mi nec magna mollis pretium. Fusce commodo elit odio, sit amet tincidunt dolor feugiat sed. Praesent risus nibh, sollicitudin vitae dictum mattis, varius ut tortor. Pellentesque dapibus metus nec nisi sollicitudin, eget dignissim massa elementum. Nulla consectetur, enim ut dapibus convallis, nisl lectus pulvinar nulla, eget dictum eros ligula sed libero. Proin ultrices rutrum est, dapibus iaculis ligula tempor non. Mauris vestibulum dolor elit, in egestas mi tempus ac. Curabitur sollicitudin turpis ut sapien dignissim vestibulum. Pellentesque vel dui eget purus elementum aliquet vitae non erat.</p>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use in relevant media query `!important` statement to override any rule specified inline by jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, try:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    nav{
         display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I tried almost exactly that earlier, however my lack of "!important" meant it was ignored - working perfectly now. :)